# PHP: Variable is int but can't perform calculation

Tags: php, int, isinteger

```
$bal = (int)$balance;
echo is_int($bal);
```

$balance is from a file_get_contents($webservice);

I am using (int) to convert a string to integer.  is_int returns 1 for true as verification.

Because the value of $bal is always negative, I do the following calculation to make it a positive:

```
$bal = $bal * -1;
```

When I do this, the value becomes 0 even though $bal may be -150 previously.

**EDIT 1**
var_dump ($balance) is returning:
string(110) "
-399.6000"

**EDIT 2** I have used XML Parser to  assign variable to array - see my answer below.

Comment: Also look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

Comment: This isn't the answer, but why not use `abs()` instead of multiply be -1. Someday `$bal` may not *always* be negative.

Comment: @Jason: Also look at comment #1 ;-)

Comment: Although you should indeed use `abs`, there is nothing wrong with the provided code, and if `$bal==-150` & `-1==-1`, it will not give you 0. More likely, there is some garbage in `$balance` (currency signs, HTML tags, whitespace etc.) which prevents it from being cast to the desired INT. Normal handling would cast it to 0 if it cannot recognize a number.

Comment: Your (int) conversion is probably not doing what you think it should be doing. What does `var_dump($balance);` say?

Comment: I get a return of 0 when I use abs($bal)

Comment: @baswoni: please provide a `var_dump($balance,(int)$balance);` output.

Comment: @janmoesen: var_dump($balance) returns: string(110) " -399.6000"

Comment: Is there anyway to clean this up?

Comment: @baswoni: `string(110) " -399.6000"` does not compute, if you're looking in a browser, please look at the _source_, not the webpage, as `-399.6000` has _far less_ then 110 characters.

Comment: I see the problem in the source. $balance is from file_get_contents ($api) and 110 chars includes the XML header data. Is there anyway to sanitize this? Source output: string(110) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<decimal xmlns="http://basw.datawareonline.co.uk/">-399.6000</decimal>"

Comment: I have solved the problem - please see my answer posted further below - I'm not able to tick this as the answer though - can someone do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I was using file_get_contents to interact with a GET method for a Web Service.

This was returning XML header data which I overlooked when assigning to a variable.

To clear out the XML to leave me with just the value I wanted, I used the PHP XML_PARSER which stored file_get_contents into an array and allowed me to assign the array value to an integer.

```
$result = file_get_contents($base);

$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $result, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);  
$bal = $vals[0]['value'];
echo $bal *-1;
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend PHP's [`abs()`-function](http://php.net/abs) if you want to make sure that you are always dealing with a positive number:

```
$bal = abs($bal);
```

Comment: I get a return of 0 when I do this.

Comment: The issue is that I've got bad data. var_dump ($balance) = string(110) " -399.6000"

Comment: @baswoni: What happens if you use [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) (probably in connection with [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim))?

Comment: you missed the $-sign in the abs-call ;) / @baswoni: you should have noticed his fault if you don't just copy&paste...

Answer (score 2):

As per your `var_dump` output, your string begins with a space. Use this:

`$bal = intval(trim($balance));`

Comment: More then a space, a space is not accounting for the other 100 missing characters :)

Comment: @Wrikken: right you are! I'm guessing his reaction was: "Oh, they don't need to see all of this junk; I'll just leave that out."

Answer (score 0):

try this to if you want to revert the sign:

```
$bal = $bal * (-1);
```

or use [abs()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.abs.php) if you want it to be always positive:

```
$bal = abs($bal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$bal = abs($bal);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$balance="-150";
$bal = $balance*1;
echo $bal;
```

gives -150

Comment: ... and has nothing to do with the question - thats about multiplying by -1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make your calculations easy by using the function intval() which returns the integer value of any variable.  Go through the function description if you have a php manual.

Comment: `(int)$var` & `intval($var)` are equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

What is your program doing with $bal after you do the multiply? The following PHP script worked as expected on my laptop:

```
<?php
$balance = "-150";
$bal = (int)$balance;
echo is_int($bal);
$bal = $bal * -1;
echo $bal;
?>
```

Output is "1150" because I didn't bother with linebreaks. Can you post any more of your code